# Two external monitors - one HDMI port, turning off laptop display

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I read somewhere that it's not possible to use two external monitors with one HDMI port (no other ports on laptop) even with splitter and making them display two different pictures because HDMI port is still sending the same signal. My question is: is it possible then to turn off laptop display as a primary screen and then to assign one of the monitors to use what laptop is suppose to show? That way I should get two different pictures on external monitor without being able to see it on laptop screen.

Comment: How are you going to connect the second monitor? What's your laptop model?

Comment: I have no other ports rather than that one HDMI port, i was just wondering if it's somehow possible to do it with windows option to turn off laptop as a primary monitor and assign it to monitor

Comment: When you use a splitter there is no other option then having the two external monitors mirror each other. You could make the external monitors primary but still won't be able to display two different things on them. Each external monitor needs its own "video port" to do that.

Comment: Oh, that's the information I needed. Thank you

Comment: As a thought you could pick up a USB to HDMI adapter pretty cheap then run one monitor off the HDMI and the other off the USB/HDMI adapter.

Comment: You the man Ziggy32, I didn't think of that.

Comment: USB video adapters can be heavy on the CPU. I'll ask again, what's your laptop model? There may be another non-trivial video output. Most laptops have two of them.

Comment: Model is Dell inspiron 3580 with i7-8565u. It has two SS usb ports, one 2.0 port, SD card slot, Ethernet port, one HDMI port and audio-out port. At least it is what I see.

Comment: Indeed it seems that USB will be your only option.